# how to extract attribute value of parent node with xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

For the xml file below, how can I extract the value of book id using xpath?

```
<catalog>
  <book id="bk101">
    <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>
       <amount>25</amount>
       <tax>12</tax>
       <total>37</total>
    </price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML</description>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

I am using the following code:

```
REGISTER hdfs:///user/iahlu/piggy.jar ;

DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

A =  LOAD '/user/iahlu/books.xml' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('book') as (x:chararray);


B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'book/price/amount'),XPath(x,'/book/price/../@id');
dump B;
```

However, my output extracts the amount, and the id field stays blank. What am I missing in the code ?

```
(25,)
(23,)
(27,)
(21,)
(31,)
```

Comment: Hello, did you try '//book/@id' or '//catalog/book/@id' as a locators?

Answer (score 1):

`id` is attribute of `<book>`, so you should be able to use simpler XPath :

```
book/@id
```

The core problem in your attempted XPath is likely the `/` before `book`. `/` at the beginning of an XPath always reference the document node. So in your case, it only works if `book` was the root element node, or if you mentioned full path from the root to `book`, like `/catalog/book/price/../@id` . To fix this, you can either remove the `/`, as shown in the first XPath above, or add `.` to make it relative to current context node : `./book/@id` .

Comment: Thank you but on trying both the options suggested above (./book/@id and book/@id) I still get the same output. No id values are extracted.